# default numeric input in TextField in j2me

Tags: java-me, calculator

I have created a simple calculator in j2me.
three `TextField`, two for input numbers,and third for result 
and commands add,sub etc.
Default mode at phone is string when entering input,(to input data ,we should change it into number mode)
Is it possible to set default mode numeric for `TextField`?

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code:

```
TextField textfield =  new TextField("Numeric", null, 8, TextField.NUMERIC);
```

Refer this [sample calculator](http://code.google.com/p/staff/downloads/detail?name=samples.Calculator-j2me-src.7z&can=2&q=label:Type-Source) application.